# Java techniques for performing action only once on selected radio button

Tags: java, radio-button

I am making a Java applet for a class, and we are using radio buttons to select delivery or carry out for a bill calculator. The delivery option has a fee, but carry out does not. I'm trying to write code that will only add the delivery fee once, regardless of how many times the delivery button is clicked.

As shown below, every time the delivery radio button is clicked, the fee is applied, and every time carryout is clicked, the amount of the delivery fee is deducted. Any ideas how to make sure the fee is just applied once for delivery or not at all for carryout?

```
// Create a panel to hold two radio buttons 
JPanel jrbOptions = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2 , 1));
jrbOptions.add(jrbPickUp = new JRadioButton("Pick Up - free"));
jrbOptions.add(jrbDelivery = new JRadioButton("Delivery - $4.00"));
jrbPickUp.setSelected(true);
add(jrbOptions, BorderLayout.WEST); 

//Create a radio button group to group two buttons
ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
group1.add(jrbPickUp);
group1.add(jrbDelivery);

jrbDelivery.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (jrbDelivery.isSelected()) {
            totalPrice += deliveryFee;  
            total.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        }
    }
});

jrbPickUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (jrbPickUp.isSelected()) {
            totalPrice -= deliveryFee;  
            total.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag which can be set when the `ActionListener` for `jrbDelivery` is triggered, for example...

```
// instance field...
private boolean feeApplied = false;

//...

jrbDelivery.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (jrbDelivery.isSelected() && !feeApplied) {
            feeApplied = true;
            totalPrice += deliveryFee;  
            total.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        }
    }
});
```

You might also be able to use this to remove the delivery fee (when `feeApplied` is `true`)

Comment: I did some further research, how about using addItemListener? If the radio button is selected, add the delivery fee, and if it moves to unselected, remove the fee.

Comment: It appears to be working for what I need, which is a pretty small task in this case. Is this something that is often used, or are if statements more common?

Comment: Based on what you're saying, this seems like a suitable solution.  You monitor the state change of the `JRadioButton` and make changes to the state of your model depending on the buttons state

Answer (score 0):

You should have a clean data model separated from UI. Delivery fee should be a separate field there. Then you can simply enable/disable the fee by modifying the data model:

This is the data model and should be in a separate class (e.g. ShoppingCart):

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    private double price;
    private double deliveryFee;
    // other fields (e.g. the list of ordered items)

    public double getTotalPrice() {
        return price + deliveryFee;
    }

    public void setDeliveryFee(double fee) {
        this.deliveryFee = fee;
    }

    // other getters/setters...
}
```

Then you can use it in your UI:

```
private ShoppingCart cart;
// ...

jrbDelivery.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (jrbDelivery.isSelected()) {
            cart.setDeliveryFee(deliveryFee); // update model
            updateUI();
        }
    }
});

jrbPickUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (jrbPickUp.isSelected()) {
            cart.setDeliveryFee(0.0); // update model
            updateUI();
        }
    }
});
```

In method `updateUI`:

```
total.setText(formatter.format(cart.getTotalPrice()));
// do other UI updates here too!
```

On submit, the `ShoppingCart` is handed over to the submit mechanism which then can retrieve the data from the object and send it to the ordering system.

Improvement: Think of making your data model bean capable of sending notifications (events) on changes. Then you can hook listeners to automatically update the UI on change!